# What design changes will improve visual appearance of the calculator

Tags: website-design, html, css, bootstrap

This is the HTML code for a very basic calculator. I am at beginner level on bootstrap and definitely beginner level designer. what are some changes i can do to make the visual appearance better. i have used bootstrap and tried to use some features to improve the look with minimum CSS ( i don't want to use CSS unless the same can be done with bootstrap ) . please use codepen link to see the rendering.

[codepen link](https://codepen.io/Demusbace/pen/VweYNNv)

HTML

```
<div class="row ml-5">
  <div class="form col-4 mt-5"> 
  <div class="form-group">
    <lable>First Number</lable>
    <input id="firstNum" type="text" class="form-control"/>
  </div>
  <div class="math-buttons">

    <div class="btn btn-primary col-12 mt-2">
       +
  </div>  <div class="btn btn-primary col-12 mt-2">
       -
  </div>  <div class="btn btn-primary col-12 mt-2">
        x
  </div>  <div class="btn btn-primary col-12 mt-2">
        /
  </div> 
  </div>


   <div class="form-group mt-3">
    <lable>Second Number</lable>
    <input id="secondNum" type="text" class="form-control"/>
  </div>
  <div id="btnCalculate" class="btn btn-primary col-12 mt-2">
        Calculate
  </div>


</div>
<div class="output col-4 my-auto ml-5">
  <h4 id="result">
    0.00
  </h4>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.math-buttons>.btn{
  display:inline;
  margin-left:10px;
}
```

Comment: A screenshot may be more user friendly than the HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 1):

The [second usability heuristic](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/match-system-real-world/) is about:

> Systems should speak the users' language with familiar words, phrases, and concepts rather than system-oriented terms. Interfaces that follow real-world conventions and make information appear in a natural and logical order demonstrate empathy and acknowledgement for users.

Keeping this in mind, people are used to physical calculators. Therefore a digital one can simply mimic the physical one in terms of layout. Familiarity instantly removes the learning curve friction and allows users to instantly use the tool without having to make sense of it. However, since digital tools offer more flexibility, actions like typing the calculation as well as showing both the calculation and the result can still be supported.

There are countless of calculators online, check Google's for example:

[image]